# How to get list of issues inside a specific project using rcarz/jira-client

Tags: java, jira

I am having a problem with get list of issues inside a specific project.I have used [Jira client API](https://github.com/rcarz/jira-client) to connect to my Jira project.My project structure something like this.

Base jira url=https://myproject.info
inside base project i have setup number of projects.like TC/CODE

so far i can connect to base project successfully and can go inside the "TC" project.In there i can get lot of attributes related to the project.But i couldn't get issues listed inside that project.(I can not see any method to obtain this)

I am new to jira client API please let me know how can i get the all issues listed in "TC" project.

```
BasicCredentials credentials=new BasicCredentials(userName,passWord);
JiraClient jira=new JiraClient("https://myproject.info",credentials);

Project tCProject= jira.getProject("TC");
System.out.println(tCProject.getLead().toString());
//How can i get the all issues inside the TC project.
```

if anyone familiar with rcarz/jira-client please let me know how can i solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get list of issues like below.

```
BasicCredentials credentials=new BasicCredentials(userName,passWord);
JiraClient jira=new JiraClient("https://myproject.info",credentials);

Issue.SearchResult sr = jira.searchIssues("Your project Name(in my case  TC)", 100);

     for (Issue i : sr.issues) {
           System.out.println(i.getSummary());
           System.out.println(i.getKey());
            etc ...

      }
```